# How to combine 2 files into third using awk?

Tags: awk

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? I have 2 files that i want to combine, taking info from the first file and putting it into the second, creating a third file.

File 1:

```
1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777=8888 | AAAA | BBBB CCCC | DDDD | 11 |
```

File 2:

```
1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777= |   | AAAA | BBBB CCCC
```

File 3 must look like this:

```
1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777=8888 |   | AAAA | BBBB CCCC | DDDD | 11 |
```

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$2]=$3; B[$1]=$2;  next} {print $1,B[$1],A[$2],$4,$5,$6 }' FS="|" OFS="|" $1 $2 > $3
echo "done"
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

@Lety this is the output after running the code:

```
1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777=8888 | AAAA | BBBB CCCC | DDDD | 11 |
1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777=8888 | AAAA | BBBB CCCC | DDDD | 11 |
1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777= | | AAAA | BBBB CCCC
1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777= | | AAAA | BBBB CCCC
1111-22-33 ||| | AAAA | BBBB CCCC
```

Comment: Can you describe, in words, what is expected ?

Comment: @Luuk it is expected to take the info from file one combine it with the info from file 2 and make the new file 3.

Comment: @Lety this is the output after running the code:
'1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777=8888 | AAAA | BBBB CCCC | DDDD | 11 |
1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777=8888 | AAAA | BBBB CCCC | DDDD | 11 |
1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777= |   | AAAA | BBBB CCCC
1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777= |   | AAAA | BBBB CCCC
1111-22-33 |||   | AAAA | BBBB CCCC'

Comment: @arm11: But "combining" two files can be done in a lot of different ways .....

Comment: @arm11: You should not post output in a comment. You can use [edit] to add it to your question, and explain why it is correct, or not.

Comment: @Luuk ok, so what do you suggest? It is really simple task btw

Comment: Can you describe, in words, how this combining should be done  ?

Comment: @Lefty please don't put answers in comments as then the community can't vote on them. What you suggested in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69287522/how-to-combine-2-files-into-third-using-awk#comment122464109_69287522) is wrong as it's setting `FS` after `FS` has already been used to split the first line and it's setting `FS` and `OFS` every time a line is read, and it's setting 2 variables to the same constant in 2 different places. It's also leaving shell variables unquoted and it's unlikely that the awk code really does whatever it is the OP needs.

Comment: @arm11 I could imagine several different ways to get the output you show from  the input you provided. Please [edit] your question to explain what values from what fields you want to use to combine the 2 files and provide a better example that really demonstrates your need. If it was a really simple task as you say in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69287522/how-to-combine-2-files-into-third-using-awk#comment122466465_69287522) then you probably wouldn't be asking for help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you might be looking for this, to combine the 2 files:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ for(i=1;i<=NF; i++) a[i]=$i; next }
     { print $1,$2, a[3],$4,$5,$6,a[7] }' FS="|" OFS="|" file1 file2
```

output:

```
1111-22-33 | 44:55:66 | 7777=8888 | | AAAA | BBBB CCCC| 11
```

But is might not meet your expectations, because I only made a wild guess at what should happen.

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=NF; i++) a[i]=$i` = `split($0,a)`.